# PHP Uploading Multiple Files With Captions To MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I've written a script to store images in my database. The images have a caption that is also uploaded and stored. This was fairly easy to get working. I have a jquery function setup to add a new file input and caption input every time I click a button. This also works.

What is not working is my PHP is not uploading multiple files for some reason.

Could someone tell me what I have done wrong?

Thanks :)

HTML:

```
<form id="uploadMultiple" method="post" action="/scripts/php/imageUploadTest" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table class="fileUploadTable" id="uploadArea" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <label for="imageFile">Image:</label> 
     <input type="file" name="imageFile" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif">
    </td>
    <td>
     <label for="imageCaption">Image Caption:</label>
     <input type="text" name="imageCaption">
    </td>
    <td width="150px">
     &nbsp;
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="uploadSubmission">
    <td>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload More" id="uploadMore">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="addImage">
    </td>
    <td width="150px">
     &nbsp;
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
```

JQuery for adding new elements:

```
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#uploadArea');
        var i = $('#p_scents tr td').size() + 1;

        $('#uploadMore').live('click', function() {
                $('<tr><td><label for="imageFile">Image:</label> <input type="file" name="imageFile" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif"></td><td><label for="imageCaption">Image Caption:</label> <input type="text" name="imageCaption"></td><td><a href="#" class="removeUpload" width="150px" style="text-align: center">Remove</a></td></tr>').insertBefore( $('#uploadSubmission') );
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('.removeUpload').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 1 ) {
                        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

And finally the PHP:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings/globalVariables.php');
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings/mysqli_connect.php');


$db_name = 'imageUploads';
$tbl_name = 'gallery';
if(!$conn)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($conn, "$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

foreach($_FILES['imageFile'] as $file){ 
$caption = $_POST['imageCaption'];
$uploadDir = 'http://www.example.com/images/'.'gallery/'; 
$fileName = $_FILES['imageFile']['name'];
$filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageFile"]["tmp_name"],$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/gallery/".$_FILES["imageFile"]["name"]))
{
$query_image = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(filename,path,caption) VALUES ('$fileName','$uploadDir','$caption')";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $query_image))
{
echo "Stored in: " . "gallery/" . $_FILES["imageFile"]["name"];
}
else
{
echo 'File name not stored in database';
}
}
}
```

I was hoping I had it working properly for multiple images with my `foreach` loop but it only uploads one image even if I have 4 selected.

EDIT:

I've tried modifying my code to this and it's not working either but looking at tutorials this seems to be more on the right track than my previous code:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings/globalVariables.php');
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings/mysqli_connect.php');


$db_name = 'imageUploads';
$tbl_name = 'gallery';
if(!$conn)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($conn, "$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

foreach($_FILES['imageFile'] as $key => $name){ 
$caption = $_POST['imageCaption'];
$uploadDir = 'http://www.jollyrogerpcs.com/images/'.'gallery/'; 
$fileName = $key.$_FILES['imageFile']['name'][$key];
$file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
$file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
$file_type= $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
$filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;

if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/gallery/".$fileName))
{
$query_image = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(filename,path,caption) VALUES ('$fileName','$uploadDir','$caption')";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $query_image))
{
echo "Stored in: " . "gallery/" . $_FILES["imageFile"]["name"];
}
else
{
echo 'File name not stored in database';
}
}
}
```

I've also added `[]` in the names of the HTML input elements that needed them.

**With help from frz3993 here is the completed working code:**

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings/globalVariables.php');
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings/mysqli_connect.php');


$db_name = 'imageUploads';
$tbl_name = 'gallery';
if(!$conn)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($conn, "$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$uploadDir = 'http://www.example.com/images/gallery/'; 

foreach ($_FILES['imageFile']['name'] as $key => $value) {

    if($_FILES['imageFile']['error'][$key] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){

         $caption = $_POST['imageCaption'][$key];
         $fileName = $_FILES['imageFile']['name'][$key];
         $file_size = $_FILES['imageFile']['size'][$key];
         $file_tmp = $_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name'][$key];
         $file_type= $_FILES['imageFile']['type'][$key];
         $filePath = $uploadDir.$fileName;

        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/gallery/".$fileName))
{
        $query_image = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(filename,path,caption) VALUES ('$fileName','$uploadDir','$caption')";
mysqli_query($conn, $query_image);

    }        
 }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to upload different files in the same form with all the inputs having the same name using the same submit button ?

Comment: Different files with different captions.. same name is possible but I'm not sure how to make that work though.

Comment: Sorry I was on mobile when i wrote that. What I mean is all the inputs will have the same name, and I've seen a few scripts use `[]` around the name sections, but every time I try that my script stops working. I'm hoping I was on the right path.

Comment: Yes, you can use the square brackets. But you will need to modify your script. `$_FILES['imageFile']['name'][0]` will contain the first file name, `$_FILES['imageFile']['name'][1]` will contain the next file name. The same with the caption `$_POST['imageCaption'][0]` will contain the first caption.

Comment: I've already added the brackets to my HTML, but I am unsure of what you mean in the script area.

Comment: `$_FILES['imageFile'] = array('name' => {thefilename}, 'tmp_name' => {the temporary name}, 'error' => {error}, 'size' => {the file size});`. This is an example how it looks like. It contains four elements. In your foreach you are basically looping through the elements in the array. That means you are basically saving the same file four times with the same name. I'll show you when I get to my laptop, out buying cigarrettes :}

Comment: I appreciate it :) I just haven't worked with uploads much period so a lot of this is still new to me :) I've been reading a few tutorials, but it's looping through the array and picking out what's needed that I am not grasping the easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I wrote in the comment `$_FILES['imageFile']` will contain some information regarding the uploaded file. I'll use four elements for example(because I don't remember what else is in it)

```
array('name' => fileName, 'tmp_name' => temporaryName, 'error' => uploadError, 'size' => theFileSize);
```

When you use `foreach` on the `$_FILES` you are actually looping through this four elements, so the lines in the loop are being run four times.

Basically you can't upload or post inputs with the same name because it will be overwritten. But you can use array as input names. For your case `name=imageFile[]` and `name=imageCaption[]`. Let say you have two uploads `image1.jpg` and `image2.jpg` with captions `caption1` and `caption2`;

The `$_FILES['imageFile']` and `$_POST['imageCaption']` structures will be like:

```
$_FILES['imageFile'] = array('name' => array(
    0 => 'image1.jpg',
    1 => 'image2.jpg'
));

$_POST['imageCaption'][0] = caption1;
$_POST['imageCaption'][1] = caption2;
```

So your foreach loop should look like

```
$uploadDir = 'http://www.jollyrogerpcs.com/images/gallery/'; 

foreach ($_FILES['imageFile']['name'] as $key => $value) {

    if($_FILES['imageFile']['error'][$key] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){

         $caption = $_POST['imageCaption'][$key];
         $fileName = $_FILES['imageFile']['name'][$key];
         $file_size = $_FILES['imageFile']['size'][$key];
         $file_tmp = $_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name'][$key];
         $file_type= $_FILES['imageFile']['type'][$key];
         $filePath = $uploadDir.$fileName;

         //your move uploaded file and sql query goes here

    }        

}
```

Comment: I've modified my code using yours and I have an error with the `move_uploaded_file` part.

I have updated my question to include the new code and errors. :)

Comment: You should use the assigned variable not the `$_FILES`. I wrote this referring to your second update. @JesseElser

Comment: Updated to variables and it's working :) Thank you so much. I believe I have a better understanding on how this works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that the .size() function is gone in the newer jQuery versions (I tested it with 3.1.1); you can use .length instead (note that .length is NOT a function and doesn't need parenthesizes).

Likewise, using .live isn't good in newer versions of jQuery and should be updated to .on()

My fixed code, working as of jQuery 3.1.1, is:

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#uploadArea');
    var i = $('#p_scents tr td').length + 1;

    $(document).on('click', '#uploadMore', function() {
        $('<tr><td><label for="imageFile">Image:</label> <input type="file" name="imageFile" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif"></td><td><label for="imageCaption">Image Caption:</label> <input type="text" name="imageCaption"></td><td><a href="#" class="removeUpload" width="150px" style="text-align: center">Remove</a></td></tr>').insertBefore( $('#uploadSubmission') );
        i++;
        return false;
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.removeUpload', function() {
        if( i > 1 ) {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```